# Karma preprocessor not running

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine, ng-html2js

My karma.conf.js includes:

```
plugins: [
    'karma-jasmine',
    'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
    'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'
],
preprocessors: {
    '../../mypath/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
},
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    moduleName: 'templates'
},
```

(I've tried without specifying any plugins, too.)

My devDependencies include:

```
"karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.2.0"`
```

My tests include:

```
beforeEach(module('templates'));
```

These give the error:

```
Module 'templates' is not available!
```

Running karma with `--log-level debug`, I do **not** see any `[preprocessor.html2js]` entries. (I do get `Loading plugin karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor.`)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issues were that the templates must be listed under `files` as well, and that the glob pattern in `preprocessors` must match. This is implied by the [documentation](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor).

```
files: [
  '../../Scripts/angular-app/directives/*.html',
  // .js files
],

preprocessors: {
  '../../Scripts/angular-app/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
},
```

Note that `**/*.html` does **not** match parent directories of the `basePath`.

`karma start --log-level debug` will display `DEBUG [preprocessor.html2js]` entries when everything is correct.

I was also able to remove the `plugins` section.

To get the correct cache ID, I used:

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    // Load this module in your tests of directives that have a templateUrl.
    moduleName: 'templates',

    cacheIdFromPath: function (filepath) {
        return filepath.substring(filepath.indexOf('/Scripts/angular-app/'));
    }
},
```

If a template references a custom filter, the filter must be loaded in `files` and the filter's module must be loaded in your directive tests.

Comment: I am getting my templatesCached and loading the module, but not accessing anything for the directives.  I am wondering what   cacheIdFromPath did for you?

Comment: @stevek I believe the goal is to transform the path into one matching a `templateUrl` in a directive. There are other ways to accomplish this, such as `stripPrefix` - see https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor . You could throw a `console.log(filepath)` in to `cacheIdFromPath` to see what you're getting and compare it to your `templateUrl`s. Your function will vary from mine.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am working on right now.  I have a strip Prefix, and the directives seem to follow that path, but when I console.log the file path I each template file is going all the way back to the root of the entire project.  I am hoping this is the problem.

Comment: @stevek I am not sure, but I think `stripPrefix` and `cacheIdFromPath` are mutually exclusive. `cacheIdFromPath` is the ultimate flexibility "do whatever you want" function, and the others are conveniences. You might try removing that function (logging and all).

Comment: Been through and logged everything.  I am wondering if you had to reference the files that were $templateCached and turned to js files inside of your files ?

Comment: @stevek I did need to include the templates used by directives in the `files` list in karma.conf.js.